# Bitcoin Core VM and hardware SHA256

Tags: bitcoin-core, cryptography, linux, sha256

It has come to my attention recently that linux machines store info about their cryptographic capabilities in `/proc/crypto`.

A baremetal machine I have shows `sha256_ssse3` in the `sha256` `module` parameter, which apparently means that some CPU instructions directly computes hashes... Turns out, a VM running on that same machine displays `kernel`. Seems that might slow things significantly cause now, some software is doing that same task instead.

Can someone attest that those flags impact Bitcoin Core's performance directly?